# How do I approximate the value of sum after the following code fragment, in terms of variable n in Big-Oh notation?

Tags: java, big-o, drjava, approximate

This is the code that was provided, I don't understand what to do at all or how to get to the answer.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n - 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n + 4; j += 5) {
        for (int k = 1; k <= n + 4; k += 5) {
                sum += 2;
        }
    }

    sum++;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    sum++;
}
```

This is also another code that was provided with the same question. If someone could explain how I am suppose the figure out the answer that would be really helpful.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum++;
}

for (int j = 1; j <= n / 2; j++) {
    for (int k = 1; k <= n / 2; k++) {
        sum++;
    }
}`
```

Comment: It's n^3 if I am not wrong. But I think this question shows lack of research, as probably the first thing that pops up on google when you write how to calculate Big O is probably this exact example, or similar.

Comment: Approximating the sum has nothing to do with Big-O notation, and there is no approximation here, or any need for it. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: But, just so that you learn, disregard the constants as O(1 + 4 + 1000 + 34324234523423) = O(1).
sum goes through the calculation some -> O((n-3)*(n+4)/5*(n+4)/5 + n + 100) -> O(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1) (disregard the constants) -> O(n^3) as n^3 >>> n^2 as n approaches infinity.
Also what @user207421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the formula which your code is implementing:

100 + (n-3)(((((n=4)/5)+1)^2)+1)
so it is N^3 order